# How to get father name in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample code:

```
products(id, parent_id, name)
1 | 0 | product1
2 | 0 | product2
3 | 1 | product1_1
4 | 1 | product1_2
5 | 2 | product2_1
6 | 2 | product2_2
```

And query:

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name
FROM `products` AS prod
INNER JOIN `products` AS prod_parent ON prod_parent.product_id = prod.parent_id
```

But result is:

```
3 | product1_1
4 | product1_2
5 | product2_1
6 | product2_2
```

How to get parent father

```
 1 | product1
 2 | product2
```

Answer (score 1):

Be specific in your `SELECT` list which table you want them from. This will give you all four columns, but you can trim it to only those you need.

```
SELECT 
  prod.id AS prod_id,
  prod.name AS prod_name,
  prod.parent_id AS parent_id,
  prod_parent.name AS parent_name
FROM `products` AS prod
LEFT JOIN `products` AS prod_parent ON prod_parent.product_id = prod.parent_id
```

Comment: @TrươngHải Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.